# Could not convert string to float: '77\xa0°'

Tags: python, valueerror

```
meteo_df = data_frame.copy()

#=======================================================  Drop useless columns
meteo_df.drop(['CONDITION'], axis=1, inplace=True)

#=======================================================  Map Wind to degrees on a circle
wdict = dict({"E": 0., "ENE": np.pi/8, "NE": np.pi/4, "NNE": 3*np.pi/8, "N": np.pi/2, 
               "NNW": 5*np.pi/8, "NW": 3*np.pi/4, "WNW": 7*np.pi/8, "W": np.pi, 
               "WSW": 9*np.pi/8, "SW": 5*np.pi/4, "SSW": 11*np.pi/8, "S": 3*np.pi/2, 
               "SSE": 13*np.pi/8, "SE": 7*np.pi/4, "ESE": 15*np.pi/8})

meteo_df.WIND = meteo_df.WIND.apply(lambda x : (wdict[x] if type(x)==str else x))
meteo_df.WIND = meteo_df.WIND.fillna(method='ffill')

#=======================================================  Reformat values by dropping units
cols = meteo_df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
meteo_df[cols] = meteo_df[cols].apply(lambda x : x.str.replace(r"[a-zA-Z\%\/²]",'').astype('float'))

meteo_df.head()
```

[csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aT68NkfeeykyLyXkqtehRgmSFmL-_TsA/view?usp=sharing)
[xlsx file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o00k7aqoa9AWvG-VVcTzN0TqT82ocgHO/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113725198561674157107&rtpof=true&sd=true)

The error occurred "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '77\xa0°'" when I tried to run the code.  [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eggSu96fgJS8xJMjw-Xm-KRCn6tkTItG?usp=sharing)

Comment: The string contains mixed numbers and text. You need to extract the numbers before you convert them to floats.. Instead of trying to replace the non-digit characters you can *split* the string and convert the first item, or use a regular expression to extract the digits at the start of the string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So how should I change my coding? I mean how to replace the non-digit or use a regular expression? How should I code it? I used this reference coding but replaced it with my own data (https://github.com/hectoramirez/Predicting_energy_consumption/blob/7570eb089aebbcc288697c5a745a052f56a6f8cc/Consumption_energy.ipynb)